# Verifying a signature with a public key

Tags: java, public-key, verify

I have an external service which call me back after some defined event, and sign his request with its private key.

I have stored the public key which look like :

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
........................................
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

So my work is to check if request's content has not been alterned by verifying signature.

Here is my algorithm :

```
// 1 - reading public key :
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File( keyPath ) );


//            encodedPublicKey.toString( );
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( );
while ( scanner.hasNextLine( ) )
{
    sb.append( scanner.nextLine( ) );
    sb.append( '\n' );
}

byte[] encodedPublicKey = sb.toString( ).getBytes( "utf-8" );

// 2 - loading public key in a relevant object :
X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec( publicKeyBytes );

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance( "DSA" );

PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic( publicKeySpec );

// 3 - verifying content with signature and content :
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance( "SHA1withDSA" );
sig.initVerify( publicKey );
sig.update( message.getBytes( ) );
ret = sig.verify( sign.getBytes( ) );
```

But for now my algorithm is stoped at "PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic( publicKeySpec )" step by this message :

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification: invalid key format
```

So how can I load my key in a way that is accepted by java api ?

Comment: Do you know what Encryption algorithm the other party used to create his private key? The error message looks to be saying you are using the wrong encryption algo, or the algo is not a part of the API. If that's the case, you may need to find an implementation of SHA1withDSA. But I think this should already be there.

Comment: Documentation says RSA, but it is not really trustable as far as I know, so I've try both RSA and DSA with same final exception result.

Comment: Hello, any progress on this? I tried compiling your example above, but it wont compile on comment item 2. Cannot find var "publicKeyBytes"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually I've found the solution.

The problem was to load in the public key file in the right way.

I'va added bouncycastle library to my dependencies :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.47</version>
</dependency>
```

It provides PemReader which allows to read and load non certificated public keys.

Here is my utility class :

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;
import org.castor.util.Base64Decoder;

import fr.paris.lutece.portal.service.util.AppLogService;


/**
 * Classe d'aide à l'interfacage avec le service paybox.
 *
 * Toutes les informations parameterables sont sous la forme paybox.*
 */
public final class PayboxUtil
{

    /** The Constant CHARSET. */
    private static final String CHARSET = "utf-8";

    /** The Constant ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM. */
    private static final String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "RSA";

    /** The Constant HASH_ENCRIPTION_ALGORITHM. */
    private static final String HASH_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "SHA1withRSA";

    /**
     * constructeur privé pour classe statique.
     */
    private PayboxUtil(  )
    {
    }

    /**
     * Controle si une signature est bien celle du message à l'aide de la clé
     * publique de l'emmeteur?.
     *
     * @param message le message
     * @param sign la signature
     * @param keyPath le chemin vers la clé publique.
     * @return true si la signature est bien celle du message avec la clé privé
     *         attendue.
     */
    public static boolean checkSign( String message, String sign, String keyPath )
    {
        boolean ret = false;

        try
        {
            ret = PayboxUtil.verify( message, sign, PayboxUtil.getKey( keyPath ) );
        }
        catch ( final FileNotFoundException e )
        {
            AppLogService.error( e );
        }
        catch ( final IOException e )
        {
            AppLogService.error( e );
        }
        catch ( final NoSuchAlgorithmException e )
        {
            AppLogService.error( e );
        }
        catch ( final InvalidKeySpecException e )
        {
            AppLogService.error( e );
        }
        catch ( final InvalidKeyException e )
        {
            AppLogService.error( e );
        }
        catch ( final SignatureException e )
        {
            AppLogService.error( e );
        }

        return ret;
    }


    /**
     * Récupère la clé publique à partir du chemin passé en paramètre.
     *
     * @param keyPath le chemin vers la clé.
     * @return la clé publique
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException the no such algorithm exception
     * @throws IOException Signals that an I/O exception has occurred.
     * @throws InvalidKeySpecException the invalid key spec exception
     */
    private static PublicKey getKey( String keyPath )
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException
    {
        final KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance( PayboxUtil.ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM );
        final PemReader reader = new PemReader( new FileReader( keyPath ) );
        final byte[] pubKey = reader.readPemObject(  ).getContent(  );
        final X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec( pubKey );

        return keyFactory.generatePublic( publicKeySpec );
    }

    /**
     * effectue la vérification du message en fonction de la signature et de la
     * clé.
     *
     * @param message le message
     * @param sign la signature
     * @param publicKey la clé publique.
     * @return true, if successful
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException the no such algorithm exception
     * @throws InvalidKeyException the invalid key exception
     * @throws SignatureException the signature exception
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException the unsupported encoding exception
     */
    private static boolean verify( String message, String sign, PublicKey publicKey )
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        final Signature sig = Signature.getInstance( PayboxUtil.HASH_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM );
        sig.initVerify( publicKey );
        sig.update( message.getBytes( PayboxUtil.CHARSET ) );

        final byte[] bytes = Base64Decoder.decode( URLDecoder.decode( sign, PayboxUtil.CHARSET ) );

        return sig.verify( bytes );
    }
}
```

You just have to pass signed content, signature and key path to checkSign method and it does all the work.