# java public key from .pub

Tags: java, public-key, plaintext

I have public key sent to me. I want to use it in encryption. But key is in .pub format. So its just a plain text, not a certificate. How do I convert this public key to an object like PublicKey key = ....;
In file I see: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANB.........
HwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----   Later I want to use this code:

```
enter code here
Private static byte[] encrypt(String text, PublicKey key) {
        byte[] cipherText = null;
        try {
          final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding");
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
          cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cipherText;
      }
```

Please someone tell me how to use .pub file to have a public key in program code.

Comment: Have you tried something like the answer provided here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691462/verifying-a-signature-with-a-public-key

Comment: In your example it is reading from .pem In my case I have only plain public key in .pub, not an a key pair or certificate.

Comment: Solution: Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
   FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
      PEMReader r = new PEMReader(fileReader);
  
          return (PublicKey) r.readObject();