# Is it Possible to validate Signature without <keyinfo> tag in XML

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

I have an Signature Embedded XML:
It does not have `<Keyinfo>`.

Is it possible to verify the signature with the public certificate (.cer).

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI="">
<Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>--Some Value--</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>--Some Value--</SignatureValue></Signature>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verifying a signature with a public key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691462/verifying-a-signature-with-a-public-key)

Comment: No.
That example has no info on validating signature without <keyinfo>